# What goes wrong in solving for an uncertainty (when expressed in quadrature)? Is there anything wrong?

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

Supposed I have the following expression for the error in an arbitrary variable S:
$\frac{\delta S}{S}=\sqrt{(\frac{\delta q}{q})^2+(\frac{\delta w}{w})^2}$. What is wrong with concluding that $\frac{\delta q}{q}=\sqrt{(\frac{\delta S}{S})^2-(\frac{\delta w}{w})^2}$? I am uncertain about the fundamental origin of the problem or whether it is wrong in the first place.

Comment: Formally that's perfectly correct, so could explain in more detail why you think it's wrong?

Comment: Well, this rule would apply to the equation S = q*w. But if I solve for q I get q = S/w. Apply the rule to that equation and I get a sum not a difference of squares, right? I think I have an idea for why it is wrong but I need to explain it to someone I am tutoring. And if I am wrong about it being wrong then I definitely need to know. FYI keywords to look up: "adding in quadrature", "uncertainty"@knzhou

Answer (score 0):

Nothing at all. But if you think that this means that you can set $\delta q = 0$, then no, you can't. The formula for computing the error in $S$ through quadrature assumes that $S$ depends on the variables $q$ and $w$ with uncertainties $\delta q$ and $\delta w$ being **independent of each other**. Thus, the formula gets values for $\delta q$ and $\delta w$ and assigns $\delta S$ a value, so that you can calculate the uncertainty *induced* in $S$ due to the uncertainties in the (independently) measured variables.

The easiest way to see this is through an example: suppose you want to measure the distance a rolling cylinder covers in some time $t$ when it's moving at some constant velocity $v$. You know that $ d = v t$, and say you further know that $v$ is precise upto 10% and $t$ up to 5%. You can add these errors in quadrature to estimate the error in $d$:

$$\frac{\delta d}{d} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\delta v}{v}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\delta t}{t}\right)^2} = \sqrt{0.1^2 + 0.05^2} \approx 11.2\%.$$

This means that given your current situation: $v$ known up to 10% and $t$ known up to 5%, your result for $d$ is only true up to 11.2%.

Now consider another person doing this experiment who is interested in measuring the speed of the cylinder. This person has the ability to measure the distance to (say) 2% and the time to 5%, and so she will measure the uncertainty in $v$ as being:

$$\frac{\delta v}{v} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\delta d}{d}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\delta t}{t}\right)^2} = \sqrt{0.02^2 + 0.05^2} \approx 5.4\%.$$

Now, you could always rearrange *your* equation to "find" $\delta{v}/v$, but it doesn't make any sense to compare it to the $\delta{v}/v$ obtained by your friend, since the uncertainty in velocity for you is a result of your measurement apparatus, while for her it's a result of an error propagation from *her* instruments. Just like it would make no sense for her to tell you that your uncertainty in distance should be 2% because *she* used a very accurate measuring scale. Does that make sense?

**Note:** Throughout this answer I have assumed that you believe the formula for the addition of (independent) errors in quadrature. As far as I know, there is no strict way of proving this, it's a "rule", just like the "rule" to use standard deviations to represent errors. It seems to work reasonably well, and there are many motivations for it, but I doubt you'll find a strict proof.

Comment: I guess I am trying to get past the precription which dictates your last equation and UNDERSTAND why there should not be a minus sign there. I have a vague intuition but I cannot put it into words.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you think there should be a minus sign there? Is it just because you can rearrange the first equation in your question to get one? What I've tried to explain in the first part of my answer is that the formulae $$\frac{\delta q}{q} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\delta S}{S}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\delta w}{w} \right)^2}$$  and $$\frac{\delta S}{S} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\delta q}{q}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\delta w}{w} \right)^2}$$ are used in two different *situations*, and therefore there's no reason for you to be able to go from one to the other...